# Alternating between CPU cores using ray

Tags: python, ray

I'm using ray to use multiples cores at the same time for a big simulation (that will take a few hours to complete). This simulation makes me repeat a function a big amount of time, and I need to make a mean of the results of these functions, so I execute them on different process to gain more time.

The thing is I don't actually want it to use all of my cores all at once (because it makes my CPU goes too high in temperature) but more like using 2 cores and once each process on those cores completed the job, switch to other cores so that those cores I used can lower in temperature. I tried to init ray with all my cpu cores, and then lauch the function on two seperate cores, wait for the results and repeat the process. The thing is that by doing it this way, it just keep using the same cores, which is what I want to avoid. Is there any way I can change that ?

Comment: What OS you are using? What Ray version are you using?
Have you tried to look for issue on GitHub?

https://github.com/ray-project/ray

If there is no issue, it would be a good idea to open one there.

Comment: Ray doesn't seem to have an API for that, which doesn't surprise me. I doubt there is even a point in doing this, unless you have physically separate CPUs. In any case, you could try using one of the various libnuma wrappers to bind the process to specific CPUs, then change the binding as you see fit. https://pypi.org/search/?q=numa&page=1